# React Native how to add dyanmic circular borders like whatsapp status

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

How to add dynamic dotted border to image view like Whatsapp doing in status screen?

I circled the functionality of that I want to achieve

[image: Whatsapp Status]

Comment: Just make dynamic circles.  What is the issue and what have you tried?

Comment: @HithamS.AlQadheeb I'm trying to make the blue borders on the status. I tried to do it with SVG Circle but failed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use svg cirlces with `stroke-dashoffset` and `stroke-dasharray` to create this effect.

In the example below `stroke-dashoffset` is calculated using `2 * PI * circleRadius / (number of items)` the second value is the spacing between each arc.

```html
<svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="48" fill="none" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" stroke-dasharray="150 2" stroke-dashoffset="-2"/>
  </svg>
<svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="48" fill="none" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" stroke-dasharray="100 2" stroke-dashoffset="-2"/> 
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the realife example using @Akshay sample code above
import React from 'react'

```
function StatusCircle() {
    const numberOfDots = 2 * 3.14 * 48 / (5) //10 number of statues //48 is the radius of the circle
  return (
      <svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
       <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="48" fill="none" 
       stroke="green" stroke-width="4" stroke-dasharray={`${numberOfDots} 2 `} 
       stroke-dashoffset={numberOfDots}/>
     </svg>
  )
}

export default StatusCircle
```